# Bluebird - How to loop through array in chunks, waiting for a chunk response

Tags: node.js

There is a way to loop through an array of ids, in chunks, and wait for the response of this chunk to continue the loop?

eg:

```
Promise = require("bluebird")

function(array){
  return Promise.*something that will loop chunks from my array and wait for each chunk response*.map(function(id){
          return myfunction(id);
        });
}
```

My problem is that I need to wait for a response from the DB that I'm accessing, and it can't answer to all calls that I'm creating at the same time. My code is raising a timeout exception because I'm being too agressive.

my code below:

```
Promise = require("bluebird")

function(array){
 return Promise.map(array, function(id){
        return myfunction(id);
      });
}
```

EDIT: 
I found a solution!

```
Promise = require("bluebird")

function(array){
 return Promise.map(array, function(id){
        return myfunction(id);
      }, {concurrency: 10});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with not using promises, the `async` module has a lot of ways to handle these scenarios. You can use `eachSeries()` if you want to make one request at a time. If you want to be a bit more efficient, you can use `parallelLimit`, which makes sure that max X callbacks are fired simultaneously.

There are also promise-versions of async, like `async-q` and bluebird-promise ports.

Comment: Yeah, I need it to be a promise. What exactly is bluebird-promise ports?

Comment: They have taken the async lib with bluebird promise integration. I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-bluebird), but it seems quite untested, so I didn't want to recommend it. But it might be good! You should check out [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=async) and see if there is any package that suits your need.

Comment: Thanks William! I found a better solution, look my edit :)